# Does JMX have limitation on size of return types?

Tags: java, size, limit, jmx

I have a Hashmap of monitoring data for each user and I connect to the monitorMbean via jmx.

I wanted to know is there any limitation on how much data jmx invocations can support? Because I have about 1000 users and per user I need about 50 long values. Is it possible to get the map of monitoring data by jmx?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So long as your server does not OOM, you should be OK. If the payload gets really big, you could gzip it and return it as a byte array, provided your client is smart enough to inflate the response. So jconsole et. al. would not work, but a custom jmx client could easily do it.